# Where can I find libc.so inside my APK file?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, ndk-build

I'm getting native crashes in Android app.

```
Crashed: Thread: SIGABRT  0x0000000000000000
#00 pc 0x51ba8 libc.so (BuildId: 8b687b4d600e1faa82af5a5197e82129)
#01 pc 0x51b78 libc.so (BuildId: 8b687b4d600e1faa82af5a5197e82129)
#02 pc 0x6d122c libart.so (BuildId: a49c773ef6221a996ecea990e9753caa)
#03 pc 0x16ea8 libbase.so (BuildId: 420d56eac27a210c92900f3ddb760c86)
#04 pc 0x6e10 liblog.so (BuildId: 28ea5154585a4fc544f1324fcd9ea010)
#05 pc 0x4aef1c libhwui.so (BuildId: 8b1c450dc05daf2fbdb01856d197d12b)
#06 pc 0x4c971c libhwui.so (BuildId: 8b1c450dc05daf2fbdb01856d197d12b)
#07 pc 0x72bb5450
#08 pc 0x4cbc4 libc++.so (BuildId: c43691f579c6316722d646cc6daa2e0e)
```

I tried to open the APK with zip and go to `myapp.zip/lib/arm64-v8a` and only found `libc++_shared.so` inside.

Questions: Where can I get the `libc.so`? I needed to find the source of crashes

Answer (score 1):

`lib.c` is a part of Android system, means "bug" is placed on Android OS side, you won't fix this by your APK code. well, you may try to avoid it by using other methods/libs at most

Comment: nuff said......

Comment: That's really sad. Assuming I have the same phone model, can I extract the `lib.c` from the device and assume they're the same? :((

Comment: @snachmsm I have a question. How is `libc++_shared.so` different with `libc.so`?

Comment: Actually I just wanted to know which line of method in `libc.so` crashed the app. I have hunch it's caused by memory leak but I can't prove it.

Comment: Use the `ndk-stack` tool included with the NDK to symbolize the stacktrace.

Comment: @flamyoad - check out [LeakCanary](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/), this lib will inspect your runtime and prompt some `Notification`, when leak occur

Answer (score 0):

From checking my own device `/system`, I'm able to find the `libc.so`. But I'm not sure if they are same even for same phone models.

[image]